# useEffect don't update when setState runs on Child Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm making a tic-tac-toe game with react, and I passed the parent setState function, to change the board, to the child component.

After that, I put a useEffect in the Parent Component ( `useEffect(()=> ... , [board])` ) to do an action whenever this state changes. But it doesn't do anything when I use the setState inside the child. The console.log below is displaying true, and that is probably the reason the useEffect is no updating.

```
function handleClick(_, i:number) {

    setBoard(prevBoard => {
  
      const newBoard = board

      newBoard[i] = dictIconToValue[icon] as typeof prevBoard[0]
  
      console.log(newBoard == prevBoard)
  
      return newBoard
  
    })

...

}
```

Comment: If the new state and old state have the same value, it won't trigger re-rendering. By the way, you should share more info on what you're doing in `useEffect` in the parent component and how you set `board` value in the child component. That would help us understand your problem better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The console.log below is displaying true, and that is probably the reason the useEffect is no updating.

That's exactly it. State in react is intended to be immutable. When you call `setBoard`, react will compare the old state with the new state using an [Object.is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) check (which is similar to `===`). If they're the same, then it looks like nothing changed, and so react skips the rerender. React will not check the properties inside your state to see if they changed, since that could be expensive.

Instead, make sure you create a new state instead of modifying the old one:

```
setBoard(prevBoard => {
  const newBoard = [...board]; // <--- creating a shallow copy
  newBoard[i] = dictIconToValue[icon] as typeof prevBoard[0]
  return newBoard
})
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as React is concerned, the state isn't actually being updated because it's still the same object reference.  You're *mutating* state instead of creating a new instance.

This doesn't copy the array, it just points a new variable to the same reference:

```
const newBoard = board
```

So any changes made to `newBoard` are being made directly on the state instance (mutating it).  Instead, create a new array with copies of the existing array's elements (which may themselves be references, but that's often an edge case and shouldn't be a problem here):

```
const newBoard = [...board]
```

In this case `newBoard` is a new object reference entirely, so when it gets set to the state then React will see it as updated state.